Dynamic Key/column Renaming in PySpark Streaming Code
I'm trying to dynamically rename a column in streaming data, but it appears that the standard approach isn't working with streaming.
My code is as below.
json_df = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(**ehConf).load()
json_df = json_df.withColumn("body", json_df.body.cast("string"))
json_df = json_df.withColumn("body", F.from_json(json_df.body, MapType(StringType(), StringType())))

# Rename the MAIN_MESSAGE column to the value of TYPE
type_value = json_df.select("TYPE").distinct().collect()[0][0]
json_df = json_df.withColumnRenamed("MAIN_MESSAGE", type_value)

The error message that I get is below
AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start(); eventhubs
the error highlights the below line
type_value = json_df.select("TYPE").distinct().collect()[0][0]

readStream() returns a streaming dataframe. It works differently. Read up on how to consume a streaming dataframe. You need to pick the right sink, depending on what you want to do. E.g.
json_df = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(**ehConf).load()
json_df = json_df.withColumn("body", json_df.body.cast("string"))
json_df = json_df.withColumn("body", F.from_json(json_df.body, MapType(StringType(), StringType())))

streaming_query = (
    json_df.select('TYPE')
    .writeStream
    .format("memory")
    .queryName("temp_type_table")
    .start()
)

# Rename the MAIN_MESSAGE column to the value of TYPE
type_value = spark.sql('select distinct TYPE from temp_type_table')[0].asDict()['TYPE']
# same as following:
# type_value = spark.read.table('temp_type_table').select('TYPE').distinct().collect()[0].asDict()['TYPE']
json_df = json_df.withColumnRenamed("MAIN_MESSAGE", type_value)

You'll also have to clean up:
streaming_query.awaitTermination()   # OR
streaming_query.stop()

# maybe drop the temp_type_table

You should also consider how you want to start your stream, using one of the triggers like availableNow or whatever fits your bill.
A blind rule of thumb, the last function call in all your streaming dataframe write operation is start() (which is your error message).
See Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();
All in all, take a few hours to read through the manual.

Thanks for getting back to me.
It seems I'm now encountering a different issue with the withColumnRenamed method:
An error occurred while calling o628.withColumnRenamed. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: [INTERNAL_ERROR] The Spark SQL phase analysis failed with an internal error. This may be a bug in Spark or the Spark plugins you’re using. Please report this bug to the relevant community or vendor, and include the full stack trace. SQLSTATE: XX000
Let me know if you have any insights on this.
